# How to configure Azure IOT central with ReadyApi

Tags: azure, iot, ready-api

We are using ourname.**azureiotcentral**.com/ and **ReadyApi 3.5.0**

[image: in Azure iot central]

An access token we created on the azureiotcentral website
looks like this:

```
SharedAccessSignature sr=739023aa-a2d4-4cc1-8044-0447586f622a&sig=teSPECIMENmawBMI0QUA5b%2BJ%2BDdhuie7JSTA%2BggltI0E%3D&skn=specimen&se=1635585779999
```

Now back in ReadyApi, which one do we choose as authentication?

[image]

next question is:
and how do you know which one to choose?
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/rest/api/iotcentral/devices/getcredentials

asuming it is ...    OAuth 2.0 (Azure)

Then how do you know the profile name?

and is the token started from the **SharedAccess** part or before the sr= or only the part after the sr=?
and why is there a spacebar in the token? (in short: how to format?)

---

I tried this:
But then the respons is  something with cookies. How do I know what browser is tested/tried?
[image]

(today: A colleague told me he thought it was the bearer option)

Comment: Hi tijnn - have you tried my answer and did it work for you? If so, I would appreciate accepting it as the answer prior to the bounty expiring. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm okay it gave good direction

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/manage-iot-central-apps-with-rest-api/3-exercise-authorize-api, the shared access signature goes in the "Authorization" header as-is without the "Bearer" prefix. I'm not sure what option that corresponds to in ReadyApi, but it might be easier to remove the authentication option and just add it manually as a header named "Authorization".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

in the field VALUE you paste the complete token, including "SharedAccessSignature" and including the spacebar before the sr=! (and yes without the Bearer, thanks Scott) that's it.